# VBA ADODB multirow insert not working

Tags: vba, excel, adodb

I am trying to figure out how to do multirow inserts using ADODB in VBA excel.
My problem seems to be that i can`t figure out the correct syntax to use for this simple task, even after searching I am still lost as to why it does not work.

I have no problem doing a single insert using the statement

```
INSERT INTO test.dbf ('field1','field3') VALUES ('test1','test11')
```

But as soon as I try

```
INSERT INTO test.dbf ('field1','field3') VALUES ('test1','test11'), ('test2','test22')
```

It gives me the following error

```
[Microsoft][ODBC dBase Driver] Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement.
```

I of course tried adding the semicolon at the end of the statement and it was no help at all, I also tried running the statement with out specifying the columns, all to no avail.

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong? I would like to avoid doing 8,000 individual inserts.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL syntax for multi-row inserts is newer than the ADODB/ODBC interfaces and so their SQL parsers do not recognize it.  Consequently your choices are:

1. Use VBA to specify this as a pass-thru query.  This should work so long as the DBMS you are executing in recognizes the new insert syntax.  However, this has the significant downside that you are almost certainly exposing your database to injection if your insert content is based on user input. (Note: this has nothing to do with pass-thru, but rather with the fact that you are using string composition to do your inserts, rather than using the ADODB table objects).
2. Just use the VBA/ADODB table objects to insert multiple rows.  This does not use the newer multi-row insert SQL syntax under-the-hood, but still works fine.  The only reason to try to leverage the multi-row syntax is if you have a performance problem, and there are many other performance options available.

Comment: Thank you, that explains it. The script parses data and inserts the result into a database for later use, so there is no user input at all. I will definitely look into your second option. I would not say I have a major performance problem at the moment, it takes around 15 minutes to run the code with a singlerow insert, and 9 min if i omit the insert statement. Considering the amount of data I am working with, I am happy with the result. However, I did not like the fact that I could not get multirow inserts working. Thank you for your help, it is greatly appreciated